# Запрос на выборку с двух связанных таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine2

Не понимаю, как правильно сделать выборку с двух таблиц. Использую Doctrine. Суть такова: игрок хочет найти подходящую ему игру, если она не находится, то создаётся новая, в которой ожидается противник. И если другой пользователь захочет найти игру, то проходим по всем ожидающим играм и ищем подходящую под тип *игры* и опыт *второго игрока*. Если не находим, создаётся новая, и т.д.

То есть:

1. Проходим по ожидающим играм;
2. Ищем игры, в которых `pending_game.type` = желаемому типу игрока. Их всего два: *cost* и *free*.
3. Так же добавить в условие, что опыт игрока и опыт противника могут отличаться только на 100 единиц. То есть, игрок с опытом 500 может играть только с игроками, у которых опыт от больше 400 меньше 600. Например: `player.experience = 500`, `pending_game.player.experience = 550`, игрок, который сейчас ищет игру, и тот, кто ожидает противника может встретиться.

```sql
CREATE TABLE player
(
    id                       INT AUTO_INCREMENT    NOT NULL,
    name                     VARCHAR(255)          NOT NULL,
    experience               INT         DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
  COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
  ENGINE = InnoDB
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE pending_game
(
    id        INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    player_id INT                NOT NULL,
    type      VARCHAR(24)        NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_57ADA99634DFEB (player_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
  COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
  ENGINE = InnoDB
```

```sql
ALTER TABLE pending_game ADD CONSTRAINT FK_57ADA99634DFEB FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES player (id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверка наличия игры:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM pending_game pg
JOIN player p1 ON p1.name = @player_name /* или p1.id = @player_id */
JOIN player p2 ON pg.player_id = p2.id 
              AND p2.experience BETWEEN p2.experience - 100 AND p2.experience + 100
WHERE pg.type = @needed_type
ORDER BY pg.id ASC 
/* раскомментировать, если нужна одна игра, иначе вернутся все, пусть выбирает */
-- LIMIT 1
```

Если предыдущий запрос не вернул записей (или игрок ничего не выбрал), то

```sql
INSERT INTO pending_game (player_id, type)
SELECT id, @needed_type
FROM player
WHERE name = @player_name 
/* или 
INSERT INTO pending_game (player_id, type)
VALUES ( @player_id, @needed_type )
*/
```

`@player_name` - имя текущего игрока

`@player_id` - ID текущего игрока

`@needed_type` - выбранный тип игры

Comment: Большое спасибо!